# skip error rows when reading data in r

Tags: r, error-handling

I'm dealing with a very large data set and there's some problem when reading data.
If I use fread, the error message is

```
Read 79.2% of 745115 rowsError in fread("~/final_top1MM.dat", na.strings = c("NA", "na", "null",  :
  Expected sep ('') but new line or EOF ends field 2614 on line 591349 when reading data: 103804269252304954413621513057004573381106206806030159757218413MAY2014-115.0425.000000126.000000000.00177358.1062711000APAC01011100001000Fusion000108581005721810380426925215130570045733811062068060301597572184-504158.125.244.229GBC21cc0010011010001002014-05-132014-05-13 03:29:25.013999769652014-05-132014-05-13 03:29:24.01399976964351843720893952419438873728257UIS00139997696101710858100572184031913999769611513057004573381106206806030159757218417815389507451886358.106266772133444.04.00.001765738606040597523.498526658374246E-7-2.0NO_DATAINVALID_TX-2ACCOUNT_INFANTNONONOMEDIP_BIN_MATCHNOCOUNTRY_MATCHNOSINGLE_IPNONONO_EVENTSONENO_NEWNO_EVENTSNO_PEEKINGOTHER0-19NO_LATNO_LATNO_LATMATCH_COUNTRYALL_FREENONONENAME_MATCHGOODCONTROLLED_HIGHUNKNOWNMEDFIXED_GEO_MATCH0.1963702538
```

And if I use read.csv, it would report can't not allocate memory. And when I delete the error rows, read.csv work fine. So I think it might not be a memory problem.

So is there any method that I could skip rows that report error whatever the error is? How could I achive this using both read.csv and fread?
Thank you in advance.